# PhpSpreadsheet \ Reader \ Exception Failed to load /root_dir/public/laravel-excel-fLRGTlw9uEE2XRz0k1fXdcg2wfs2RWy7.html as a DOM Document

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, export-to-excel, laravel-excel

I have tried everything for resolving this issue but nothing worked.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Also Updated my Dependencies

```
composer dump-auto -a
composer update
```

But Nothing of these things have helped me

Please respond some asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was that there was a **Closing Anchor** Tag, that was making the issue because while generating the Excel there must be no extra things or missing only **Pure HTML table** works for excel file generation nothing else

Answer (score 0):

My issue was caused by an ampersand character, I had to change it to `&amp;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).